# Can 'get stuffed' be used in a more literal way, instead of 'stuff oneself' (with food, for example)?

Tags: word-usage, idioms

'I'm starving! I'm going to go to Chick-fil-A and get stuffed', does it sound okay to a native's ear? British people would use it in a whole different sense but maybe a literal usage of that phrase would be fine with Americans, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiom in English is: to stuff one's face.

I'm going to Chick-fil-A to stuff my face.

not: to get stuffed, which really would be comical, as it would mean to get screwed or to be stuffed as one stuffs a turkey.

I don't usually cite the Free Dictionary but it works fine here for a "reference":

> slang To eat a lot of food, especially quickly and in a short period
>   of time.

[stuff one's face](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stuff+my+face)

Comment: I agree. An interesting side, note, though: We can use _stuffed_ to describe our state after we've eaten. So, while we wouldn't say, "I'm going to Chick-fil-A to **get** stuffed," we might well say, "When I left the Chick-fil-A I **was** stuffed.

Comment: @J.R. Of course. You even make a joke of it: I went to Chik-fil-A and got stuffed. What am I? A turkey, can't you tell.  You might then ask, what the heck was a turkey doing at a chicken place?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a native English speaker from Canada, so my English is pretty close to American.

You could use it the way you want, but you would have to say "**to** get stuffed". You will be understood the way you intend and it won't sound weird.

You do have to be careful how you use it. It's true that we don't often use the phrase "get stuffed" the way the British do, but it is largely known that it is a British expression. So if I hear "get stuffed" I think of the way the British use it. So the context is key.

Comment: to stuff my face

Comment: Agree that I would be weary of using "to get stuffed" without sufficient context. I am more likely to say, "feel stuffed", after having eaten a good meal.